# dotnet core on 32bit Ubuntu

Tags: 32bit, .net

I want to install dotnet core on a 32bit Xubuntu 16.04.

Unfortunately https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#ubuntu seems to be aimed towards amd64. Is there a way to install dotnet core on a 32bit system?

According to hardinfo my system looks like this:

Kernel      : Linux 4.4.0-38-generic (i686)
Compiled        : #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 6 15:41:41 UTC 2016
C Library       : Unknown
Default C Compiler      : GNU C Compiler version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2)
Distribution        : Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Comment: [this question has been answered on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43405642/is-installing-net-core-on-32bit-ubuntu-possible). Short answer no.